# Fine-Uploader FTP uploads

Tags: fine-uploader

I just have to find out, as I'm quite new and I've been digging into this for many hours now, but I just need to make sure it's possible to use Fine-Uploader to upload files on a php site to a remote SFTP server.

To be specific, I have a webserver with a php site, and I need to have an upload function for graphic files that will go to a locally hosted SFTP server. If you can at least confirm for me that this is possible, I think I can figure out the rest with docs.

So far, I've downloaded the git for fine-uploader, installed npm, installed grunt, built the git repository, and now I believe I have to add server side php handlers.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fine Uploader only understands HTTP; not FTP. That being said, you could easily have Fine Uploader uploading files to an endpoint on your server, and then -- maybe after some server-side processing -- serve those files over (S)FTP -- or any other protocol -- if you would like.

Fine Uploader's primary goal is to normalize the file upload experience in all browsers. The pros of using this over an FTP client would be that any user that has a web browser should theoretically be able to upload files to your service. What your service does with those files afterwards (whether that be hosting them on an FTP server, transcoding multimedia files, etc) is completely up to you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that answers everything I need to know. It seems like there is no solution for a webpage capable of sftp'ing a user file to another server with hidden static sftp settings! The hunt continues...

Comment: Unfortunately, pure FTP via client-side JS is just not possible yet. Maybe some hybrid FTP-over-HTTP project exists somewhere, but I have not heard of it. The most feasible solution is the one I described above in which you would have a server to receive uploads via HTTP and then share that directory via (S)FTP. More or less, you'd be mapping Fine Uploader's requests to the "shell" commands that FTP would execute. You could do this all over secure protocols, and even use a library to verify keys and such (a la public and private keys for SSH). I'd like to see this work!